# How to seggregate by sex

Tags: r

I am very new to R. I am using the package MASS and in that, the dataset 'cats.'  I am trying to seggregate the data into male and female cats then obtain the summary statistics of the data on each sex.

Comment: Can you post your `R` code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `aggregate` function if you have custom queries you need to perform!

```
> library(MASS)
> data()
> aggregate(cbind(Bwt, Hwt)~Sex,FUN=mean, data=cats)

  Sex      Bwt       Hwt
1   F 2.359574  9.202128
2   M 2.900000 11.322680
```